# How to disable GPU acceleration in JxBrowser via environment variable or config file?

Tags: vaadin, jxbrowser

JxBrowser (which used by Vaadin Designer) fail to work with  my video card driver, as Chromium too.

With the `--disable-gpu` option, it works fine.

Because Vaadin Designer control JxBrowser lifecyle I can't pass options via command line.

How can I pass `--disable-gpu` option to JxBrowser via environment variable or config.file ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using the setChromiumSwitches() method of the BrowserPreferences class.
Please take a look at the sample below:

```
BrowserPreferences.setChromiumSwitches("--disable-gpu");
```

Comment: Thanks, but the aim is: "to pass --disable-gpu option via environment variable or config.file" because I have no access to Vaadin Designer source code to control how it starts JxBrowser.

Comment: JxBrowser doesn't allow disable GPU via an environment variable or configuration file.